# Difference between NewIndexerInformer and NewSharedIndexInformer

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a question regarding the difference between `NewIndexerInformer` and `NewSharedIndexInformer` as I would like to use `NewSharedIndexInformer` instead `NewIndexerInformer`

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L132 and

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/cache/controller.go#L307

in `NewIndexerInformer` I pass the `ResourceEventHandler` but in `NewSharedIndexInformer` I cannot, this means I don't need to specify events of creation, deletion, etc?

I am doing the following https://pastebin.com/kqvQpDLU in line 226 and 251

Thanks in advance

Comment: SharedInformers share the connection with the API server and other resources between your informers. According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59544139/kubernetes-client-go-watch-interface-vs-cache-newinformer-vs-cache-newsharedi