# Kubernetes client-go: watch.Interface vs. cache.NewInformer vs. cache.NewSharedIndexInformer?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I need my Go app to **monitor some resources** in a Kubernetes cluster and react to their changes. Based on numerous articles and examples, I seem to have found a few ways to do it; however, I'm relatively new to Kubernetes, and they're described in terms much too complex to me, such that I'm still **unable to grasp the difference** between them — and thus, to know which one to use, so that I don't get some unexpected behaviors... Specifically:

1. [`watch.Interface.ResultChan()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/watch#Interface) — (acquired through e.g. [`rest.Request.Watch()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/rest#Request.Watch)) — this already seems to let me react to changes happening to a resource, by providing `Added`/`Modified`/`Deleted` events;
2. [`cache.NewInformer()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache#NewInformer) — when I implement a [`cache.ResourceEventHandler`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache#ResourceEventHandler), I can pass it as last argument in:

   ```
   cache.NewInformer(
           cache.NewListWatchFromClient(clientset.Batch().RESTClient(), "jobs", ...),
           &batchv1.Job{},
           0,
           myHandler)
   ```

   — then, the `myHandler` object will receive `OnAdd()`/`OnUpdate()`/`OnDelete()` calls.

   To me, this seems more or less equivalent to the `ResultChan` I got in (1.) above; one difference is that apparently now I get the "before" state of the resource as a bonus, whereas with `ResultChan` I would only get its "after" state.

   Also, IIUC, this is actually somehow built on the `watch.Interface` mentioned above (through `NewListWatchFromClient`) — so I guess it brings some value over it, and/or fixes some (what?) deficiencies of a raw `watch.Interface`?
3. [`cache.NewSharedInformer()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache#NewSharedInformer) and [`cache.NewSharedIndexInformer()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache#NewSharedIndexInformer) — <sub><sup>(uh wow, now *those* are a mouthful...)</sup></sub> I tried to dig through the godocs, but I feel completely overloaded with terminology I don't understand, such that I don't seem to be able to grasp the subtle (?) differences between a "regular" `NewInformer` vs. `NewSharedInformer` vs. `NewSharedIndexInformer`...

Could someone please help me **understand the differences** between above APIs in the Kubernetes client-go package?

Answer (score 36):

These methods differ in the **level of abstraction**. If a higher level abstraction fits your need, you should use it, as many lower level problems is solved for you.

**Informers** is a higher level of abstraction than *watch* that also include *listers*. In most use cases you should use any kind of Informer instead of lower level abstraction. An Informer internally consists of a *watcher*, a *lister* and an *in-memory cache*.

**SharedInformers** share the connection with the API server and other resources between your informers.

**SharedIndexInformers** add an index to your data cache, in case you work with a larger dataset.

It is recommended to use SharedInformers instead of the lower level abstractions. Instantiate new SharedInformes from the same **SharedInformerFactory**. Theres is an example in [Kubernetes Handbook example](https://github.com/feiskyer/kubernetes-handbook/blob/master/examples/client/informer/informer.go)

```
informerFactory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactory(clientset, time.Second*30)

podInformer := informerFactory.Core().V1().Pods()
serviceInformer := informerFactory.Core().V1().Services()

podInformer.Informer().AddEventHandler(
    // add your event handling 
)

// add event handling for serviceInformer

informerFactory.Start(wait.NeverStop)
informerFactory.WaitForCacheSync(wait.NeverStop)
```

Comment: What lower level problems? — I don't seem to see any with Watcher, and I am specifically anxious what I might be missing? Also, does the "in-memory cache" help me in any way if I'm just listening to resource change events? Finally, does the connection sharing happen "magically" through client-go's internal global vars, or do I have to arrange for this somehow, e.g. by ensuring they're built from the same ListerWatcher, or something else? As to index = for larger dataset, this seems to clear that aspect up, thanks!!!

Comment: @akavel by just using watch, you may miss events (e.g. network problems) sometimes and it can be solved by regularly do a _list_ request... all this is handled for you with _Informers_. Yes, sharedInformers will be shared automatically, but you need to use the same **sharedInformerFactory** to instantiate them.

Comment: so, if I just run `NewSharedInformer`, it will *not* be shared with anything, unless I get hold of some preexisting `SharedInformerFactory`? What's the point of this func then? If I don't have access to a factory, I can just create a non-shared `NewInformer` and it will be no different?

Comment: @akavel those are building blocks that the factory will call. See my code example on how to use `SharedInformerFactory` and it has fewer parameters, fewer technical details that the developer need to think about - higher abstractions.

Comment: Thanks; your answer is definitely helpful; though you skipped answering some of the clarification questions I posed, which leaves me still with a lot of doubts, so I'm not ready to mark this as the Accepted Answer in its current state.

Comment: This should be the intro to the java library also, which is absolutely terribly described. Thank u for the answer.

Comment: I also have the same doubts. Can any of you please clarify if possible?